# Updating an app that has sensitive permissions on the Google Play Console

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, google-play-console

I'm am trying to update my app on Google Play Console. I have releases in the open/internal tracks that are non-compliant as an early app version had the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.

I have since removed this permission, created new releases (for each track) and uploaded a new app bundle that should be compliant.

I still get the message:

"You can't submit updates as some information about your app is incomplete".

When I start the "Sensitive permissions and APIs" it's still referring to my early releases and not my new ones.

How can I deactivate them?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you made sure that all required sections for the listing have been filled? For example, Main Store Listing, and App Content?

Comment: Yes, all green ticks except for "Sensitive permissions and APIs"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a solution as yet, but I'm in exactly the same position and contacted Google Play Developer Support to ask how to submit the version of the app that removes the permission.

Their response was:

> You will have to declare the permission QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES first in order to update newer versions. Once you've successfully updated the app without the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, it will naturally be removed in your app bundle explorer.
>
> Please note that removing the permission without declaring it first is not possible at the moment.

Like you, the permission came from a plugin used in an older version of the app and I never actually used the functionality that required it, so I have no way of providing them with a video of it's usage.

I have put this to them and am awaiting a response on how they suggest I should proceed.

-- UPDATE --

I just tried completed the declaration by entering an explanation like the above, ticking "App functionality" and put one of my app's promotional youtube videos in the video box.

This went straight through, and after refreshing the release page a few minutes later I was able to submit the updates for both production and closed testing.

So, basically, just fill out the form with something to unlock submission of your new version.!

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that you have already filled all the required sections on the 'App Content' and submitted it, all you have to do is refresh the page then you can roll out your app. This did take me some time :(

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still facing a permissions issue: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150?hl=en#How%20to%20remove%20location%20in%20the%20background

It seems when you upload a new release you have to make sure the old version with the permissions is inactive.  This took me a while to understand so I thought I'd post.